# Drop nested Lists in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider :

```
Tuples[Range[1, 3], 2]
```

[image]

I would like to drop some of the sublist based on the following list :

sublistToTemove = {1,2,3,6,8}

Desired Output :

{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}

Corresponding to the 4th, 5th and 7th elements of list.

I have tried Drop, Case, Select without success, must be missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your list:

```
In[2]:= lst = Tuples[Range[1, 3], 2]

Out[2]= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3,2}, {3, 3}}
```

and

```
In[5]:= sublistToTemove = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8}

Out[5]= {1, 2, 3, 6, 8}
```

Here are 2 ways:

```
In[6]:= Delete[lst, List /@ sublistToTemove]

Out[6]= {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}

In[7]:= lst[[Complement[Range[Length[lst]], sublistToTemove]]]

Out[7]= {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}
```

Comment: Leonid, in what situation would you use the second method?  Also, what is "Temove"? I thought it was a typo, but Sasha uses it as well!

Comment: @Mr. Wizard Temove was copied from the OP, I guess we both did not catch the typo.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just illustrated two different lines of thought: to delete, you can either delete explicitly, or extract the remaining elements. Also, if the original list is large and unpacked, and the list of positions to delete also large, the second method can be  an order of magnitude faster - `Delete` can be quite slow for large number of deletions from unpacked lists.

Answer (score 7):

```
In[15]:= sublistToTemove = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8};

In[16]:= Delete[Tuples[Range[1, 3], 2], Transpose[{sublistToTemove}]]

Out[16]= {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}
```